# Save excursion in an Org Agenda buffer?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, save-excursion

I have a function that executes `save-excursion` from within an Org Agenda buffer, but it doesn't return the point to the agenda buffer once the body of the excursion finishes executing. Here is the function I call:

```
(defun link-headline-from-agenda ()
  "From an agenda window, link the corresponding headline to the selected file."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (org-agenda-goto)
    (link-headline)))
```

Is there a way to make save-excursion work as expected or get similar behavior inside an org agenda buffer?

Comment: If you are leaving the `*Org Agenda*` buffer to go to a source buffer and wish to keep the new window configuration, then you may wish to record the initial *point/window/buffer* in let-bound variables and then return to that *point/window/buffer* when you are done.  If you wish to restore the window layout, then have a look at `save-window-excursion`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Configurations.html  The `*Org Agenda*` buffer is a summary containing excerpts from one or more source files -- when acting on a source file, a user leaves the agenda buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the solution was in the source files. Agenda commands that operate on the corresponding buffer save the org buffer attributes, then operate on them using `with-current-buffer`. Here is my working version of the above function:

```
(defun link-headline-from-agenda ()
  "From an agenda window, link the corresponding headline to the selected file."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((marker (org-get-at-bol 'org-marker))
     (buffer (marker-buffer marker))
     (pos (marker-position marker)))
    (org-with-remote-undo buffer
      (with-current-buffer buffer
    (goto-char pos)
    (link-headline)))))
```